# Passing a variable from a function back to a function in Dojo

Tags: javascript, dojo, return, global-variables, parameter-passing

I have a question. My intervalValue in the start function is undefined. But in the microflow function it is the value I want to have. How can I return the value in the microflow function back to the start function. I have tried basic global and return implementations of javascript, but that doesn't work and the dojo.global isn't clear enough for me know how to implement. All help is appreciated. See my code below:

```
start : function() {
    this.addOnLoad(dojo.hitch(this, function() { //make sure the thing only starts when completely loaded!
        if (this.once)
            this.handle = window.setTimeout(dojo.hitch(this, function() {
                this.intervalexecute();
                console.log("addOnLoad " + this.intervalValue);
                this.execute();
                this.stopped = true;
            }), this.intervalValue);
        else {
            this.intervalexecute();
            console.log("addOnLoad " + this.intervalValue);
            if (this.startatonce)
                this.execute(); //invoke directly as well
            this.handle = window.setInterval(dojo.hitch(this, this.execute), this.intervalValue);
        }
    }));
},
intervalexecute : function() {
    if (this.dataobject != null && this.dataobject.getGUID && this.dataobject.getGUID())
    {
        //microflow set, not already calling a microflow            
        mx.processor.xasAction({
            error       : function() {
                logger.error(this.id + "error: XAS error executing microflow");
            },
            actionname  : this.intervalmicroflow,
            applyto     : 'selection',
            guids       : [this.dataobject.getGUID()],
            callback    : dojo.hitch(this, this.microflowresult)
        });             
    }
},
microflowresult: function(result) {
    if (result) {
            this.intervalValue = dojo.fromJson(dojo.isIE ? result.xhr.responseText : result.xhr.response).actionResult;
            console.log("result: " + this.intervalValue);
        }
},
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason interval value is not set is because microflowresult is an asynchronous function. Your logging statement in start is executed before microflowresult is called.

You need to have your callback do any processing on intervalValue.